# How to show map control on windows mobile application and which service is providing that?

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-gps

I am searching for

1. How to use map control on windows mobile 6?
2. Which service i have to use for this?

Can any one help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a standard map control for Windows Mobile. You first need to find a service and design a control of your own. Among others, you can use [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/signup.html) and [Yahoo Maps](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/).

Yahoo Maps have a REST API. This means that in the simplest solution, you could use a WebBrowser control and point the URL to the map image.